# Static factories - good practice?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, logging, static, factory-pattern

I've got a static log manager class that should return instances of a desired logger based on a parameter.

```
public static class LogManager {

    private static ILoggerFactory Factory { ... }

    public static ILogger GetLogger(string name) {
        return Factory.Create(name);
    }

}
```

Since the concrete implementation of ILoggerFactory must be set (initialization), I'm wondering if I should only keep a reference on the type of the implementation and return a new instance everytime the factory is requested - or if it's okay to keep a static reference of an instance of the implementation.

**Version 1**

```
private static Type _factoryType;

public static void SetFactory<TFactory>()
    where TFactory : ILoggerFactory, new()
{
    _factoryType = typeof(TFactory);
}

private static Factory {
    get { return (ILoggerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(_factoryType);
}

public static ILogger GetLogger(string name) {
    return Factory.Create(name);
}
```

**Version 2**

```
private static ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

public static void SetFactory<TFactory>()
    where TFactory : ILoggerFactory, new()
{
    _loggerFactory = (ILoggerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance<TFactory();
}

public static ILogger GetLogger(string name) {
    return _loggerFactory.Create(name);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably, main difference appear to be in the lazy loading: v1 will create logger type when `GetLogger` is called, whereas v2 will create logger during `SetFactory`. There is not much of a difference otherwise. It is OK to keep a reference as a private static field to either the type of a logger or the factory itself.

However, if this is production code, I'd get rid of this log manager and factories altogether. Instead I'd use logging framework, like nlog or log4net *directly*. This simplifies code and makes it more maintainable. Building abstraction in this case is over-engineering.

Comment: Ah, the old 'abstracting away logging framework' discussion. In most of our applications, our company used log4net directly for years. However, for some we needed to switch on different 'frameworks', like System.Diagnostics.TraceSource and EntLib for certain purposes. And we're even now discussing about switching to NLog. We came to the conclusion that it's easier if every developer logs the same way in every application, but we still can switch to a different framework if the requirements change between applications. So - why not abstracting the decision of what framework to take away?